# How to set host port in Plari software

Tags: settings, irc

In adding *new network*, I didn't find any option to set custom port.
So is it possible to connect to a IRC server with different port in Polari software?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just need to add *port* after server address.

for example:

```
irc.myserver.domain:6678
```